# Can I declare / use some variable in LINQ? Or can I write following LINQ clearer?

Tags: c#, linq

Can I declare / use some variable in [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)?

For example, can I write following LINQ clearer?

```
var q = from PropertyDescriptor t in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        where (t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name) != null)
        select t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name);
```

Are there ways to not write / call `t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name)` two times here?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
var q = from PropertyDescriptor t in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        let u = t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name)
        where (u != null)
        select u;
```

Comment: Using a capital T for a local variable is pretty confusing, since normally you would expect T to be a generic type parameter.

Comment: @Joren thanks, I understand that rule and ALWAYS apply it in my code. I just wanted to use a capital letter to distinct it and I thought of letter T for no clear reason, another reason is I wanted to type it as fast as possible, many others can understand it. Maybe in a `SQL-like query`, I see using capital letters is not really bad, especially **variable names of only 1 letter**, it even makes the code clearer. Don't you feel like that?

Comment: @KingKing, variable names shouldn't be starting with a capital letter unless they are properties. The convention is to use `T` to mean a generic type, which means that using `T` as a variable name will have the effect of making your code harder to read.

Comment: @zzzzBov I know the rule, I just used it here in this answer (not in my real project), as I said, it looks clearer, more distinct (at least in the case of this question where the OP wants to know if he can declare some variable in linq expression). Thanks!

Comment: Um, am I the only one that finds *all* one-letter variable names confusing, upper-case or not? Excluding the usual industry-wide exceptions, of course (i, j, etc. for loop indices, T for type parameters).

Comment: @MattPeterson And also the ones used in lambdas? For example, if you have an `IEnumerable<string> names`, when you call `.Select` you normally pass `s => s.Trim()` instead of `name => name.Trim()`.

Answer (score 84):

You need `let`:

```
var q = from PropertyDescriptor t in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        let name = t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name)
        where (name != null)
        select name;
```

If you wanted to do it in query syntax, you could do it in a more efficient (afaik) and cleaner way:

```
var q = TypeDescriptor
            .GetProperties(instance)
            .Select(t => t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name))
            .Where(name => name != null);
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, using the `let` keyword:

```
var q = from PropertyDescriptor t in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
    let nameProperty = t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name)
    where (nameProperty != null)
    select nameProperty;
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an alternative that few people know about ( `select a into b`):

```
var q = from PropertyDescriptor t in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        select t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name) into u
        where u != null
        select u;
```

This translates into:

```
var q = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        .Select(t => t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name))
        .Where(prop => prop != null);
```

Whereas the `let`-based version translates to:

```
var q = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)
        .Select(t => new { t, prop = t.ComponentType.GetProperty(t.Name) })
        .Where(x => x.prop != null)
        .Select(x => x.prop);
```

An unnecessary allocation per item because `t` is still in scope (yet unused). The C# compiler should just optimize that away, but it doesn't (or the language spec does not allow it, not sure).

Comment: Heh, thought that `let` was inefficient. I provided the answer with your optimization as an option. Little did I know it could be done in query syntax. +1.