# Putting two lists together in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, windows, linq, google-maps, foreach

I'm kinda new to LINQ and programming. What I want to do is to put two different lists together so instead of using two foreache-loops I want to get the information with Linq.
I'm gonna show you my example of code:

```
  Country c = CountriesHandler.GetCountry(startPage.SelectedCountry);
            if (globalSite)
            {
                List<Marker> markersForGlobal = new List<Marker>();
                foreach (var user in userList)
                {
                    Country ce = CountriesHandler.GetCountry(user.GetAttributeValue<string>("Country"));

                    foreach (var u in photoWithInfo)
                    {
                        if (user.ID == u.UserID)
                        {
                            int id = u.UserID;
                            string im = u.SquareThumbnailUrl;

                            markersForGlobal.Add(new Marker
                                   {
                                       Id = id,
                                       Image = im,
                                       Longitude = ce.Longitude,
                                       Latitude = ce.Latitude
                                   });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Json(markersForGlobal);
            }
```

So this is what it looks like and right now it takes alot of "memory" from the site to list this out on google maps so I think u can do this with a better solution.
Thanks for your time

Comment: What is `photoWithInfo`?

Comment: photoWithInfo is properties called to the database like userID,image
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could try is by using a LINQ query that would be similar to the one given below. The one downside is that GetCountry is called twice.

```
var result = from pwi in photoWithInfo
                     join user in userList on pwi.UserId equals user.UserId
                     select new Marker()
                     {
                         Id = user.UserId,
                         Image = pwi.SquareThumbnailUrl,
                         Longitude = CountriesHandler.GetCountry(user.GetAttributeValue<string>("Country")).Longitude,
                         Latitude = CountriesHandler.GetCountry(user.GetAttributeValue<string>("Country")).Latitude
                     };
```

Comment: You should use `let` to avoid executing the `GetCountry` twice, you should also apply `ToList()` on the last result to suit the OP's requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much! Be my best friend? hahaha ! :D

Comment: How do you mean with let? never used it b4 :(
@KingKing

Comment: @user2862542 `let` is the key word allowing us to **define** some variable in `expression linq query`, try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057090/can-i-declare-use-some-variable-in-linq-or-can-i-write-following-linq-clearer/18057121#18057121

Comment: Thank you so much @KingKing but I don't need to use Let here, still working hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would be done in your example since you use the first list to obtain the data that needs to go into other list. I don't know what your method to GetCoutry does but that might be your bottleneck if it is going on DB often or if it another service you are calling. Instead of doing a action for each user repeatedly try to get all of the countries with one call for all the users in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your time Rob!
I'm thinking about using a metod where I make a JOIN in the database where I get all  the countries from my table and then join it with a user or something.. hm hehe

Answer (score 0):

Try this linq, I don't think that it will decrease memory but for sure it's more elegant :)

```
var markers = new List<Marker>();

userList.ForEach(user =>
{
    var country = CountriesHandler
                    .GetCountry(user.GetAttributeValue<string> ("Country"));

    markers.AddRange(photoWithInfo.Where(info => user.Id == info.UserID)
        .Select(info => new Marker
            {
                Id = info.UserID,
                Image = info.SquareThumbnailUrl,
                Latitude = country.Latitude,
                Longitude = country.Longitude
             }));
    });
```