# Setting a Variable in a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am applying filters to a query and I am trying to set a variable value within one of the filters. I've tried various online examples, but each fails in different ways.

**Q:** How can I set the `MeterObjectState` variable in the example below?

I have tried:

- Using [LET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057090/can-i-declare-use-some-variable-in-linq-or-can-i-write-following-linq-clearer)
- Using `SELECT( x=> { x.MeterObjectState = dataitems.Workflow; return x; })`

...and others.

**DATA TRANSFER OBJECT SAMPLE:** 
This is partial list of properties:

```
public class DeviceDataItem
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public int? MeterId { get; set; }

    public string MeterName { get; set; }

    public Workflow MeterObjectState { get; set; } //<-- I am trying to set this

    // Other properties omitted ...
}
```

**METER WORKFLOW FILTER:** 
I want to do something like `dataitems.Workflow = statefulDevice.Workflow`

```
public IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> MeterWorkflowFilter(IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> query)
{
    Type context = typeof(Meter);

    var deviceState = (from objectState in UnitOfWork.ObjectState
                       join workflow in UnitOfWork.Workflow 
                       on objectState.WorkflowId equals workflow.Id
                       where objectState.ContextFullName == context.FullName
                       group objectState by objectState.ContextId into grp
                       select grp.OrderByDescending(desc => desc.CreateDate)
                       .FirstOrDefault());

    // NOTE: Here is where I have access to "statefulDevice.Workflow"
    // and want to do something like "dataitems.Workflow = statefulDevice.Workflow"
    var filteredQuery = (from dataitems in query //<-- QUERY
                         join statefulDevice in deviceState 
                         on dataitems.MeterId equals statefulDevice.ContextId 
                         into statefulDeviceLEFTJOIN
                         from statefulDevice in statefulDeviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select dataitems.Workflow = statefulDevice.Workflow);

    return filteredQuery;
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUERY FILTER:** 
You shouldn't need this to answer the question...but people often ask for more detail

```
public IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> Query()
{
    var query = from device in UnitOfWork.Device
                join rtuDevice in UnitOfWork.RTUDevice on device.Id equals rtuDevice.DeviceId into rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN
                    from rtuDevice in rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join commTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.CommunicationTechnicianId equals commTech.Id into commTechLEFTJOIN
                    from commTech in commTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join measureTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.MeasurementTechnicianId equals measureTech.Id into measureTechLEFTJOIN
                    from measureTech in measureTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meter in UnitOfWork.Meter on device.Id equals meter.DeviceId into meterLEFTJOIN
                    from meter in meterLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meterType in UnitOfWork.MeterType on meter.MeterTypeId equals meterType.Id into meterTypeLEFTJOIN
                    from meterType in meterTypeLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join company in UnitOfWork.Company on meter.CompanyId equals company.Id into companyLEFTJOIN
                    from company in companyLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meterPosition in UnitOfWork.EFMMeterPosition on meter.EFMMeterPositionId equals meterPosition.Id into meterPositionLEFTJOIN
                    from meterPosition in meterPositionLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join runStatus in UnitOfWork.RunStatus on meter.RunStatusId equals runStatus.Id into runStatusLEFTJOIN
                    from runStatus in runStatusLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join pipeline in UnitOfWork.Pipeline on meter.PipelineId equals pipeline.Id into pipelineLEFTJOIN
                    from pipeline in pipelineLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new DeviceDataItem()
                {
                    DeviceId = device.Id,
                    DeviceName = device.DeviceName,
                    MeterPositionId = meterPosition.Id,
                    MeterPositionCategory = meterPosition.EFMMeterPositionCategory,
                    MeterId = meter.Id,
                    MeterName = meter.MeterName,
                    MeterNumber = meter.MeterNumber,
                    MeterTypeId = meterType.Id,
                    MeterTypeName = meterType.MeterTypeName,
                    CompanyId = company.Id,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                    PipelineId = pipeline.Id,
                    PipelineName = pipeline.PipelineName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianId = commTech.Id,
                    CommunicationTechnicianFirstName = commTech.FirstName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianLastName = commTech.LastName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianId = measureTech.Id,
                    MeasurementTechnicianFirstName = measureTech.FirstName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianLastName = measureTech.LastName,
                    RunStatusId = runStatus.Id,
                    RunStatusCategory = runStatus.RunStatusCategory,
                };

    return query;
}
```

**USAGE:** 
You shouldn't need this to answer the question...but people often ask for more detail

```
var application = (MeasurementContractsApplication)MeasurementContracts;
var provider = (DeviceDataItemProvider)application.DeviceDataItemProvider;

var query = provider.Query();
var publishedDevices = provider.PublishedDevicesFilter(query);
var meterByWorkflow = provider.MeterWorkflowFilter(query);

var collection = meterByWorkflow.ToDataSourceResult(request).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just iterate your result set with a foreach loop?

Comment: I dont want to Materialize the query until the end.  Plus, i already have access to "statefulDevice.Workflow".  But every method I try fails. And, it is driving me nuts :-)

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but you need to materialize the query if you want to set properties on the resulting objects, right?

Comment: @Rufus No, you do not need to do so.  Think of it as appending to a query

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: that makes no sense. You cannot set the property value of an object that is not yet instantiated. Hence why `NullReferenceException` exists, because it is impossible to refer to the property of a non-existant object, let alone set its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate posting my own answer.  If anyone comes up with a more eloquent solution, I will gladly mark theirs as correct.

**STEPS:**

1. Add "MeterObjectState" into the original queries SELECT CLAUSE
2. When setting a new property make sure to return the same SELECT CLAUSE for each "Filter"

**EXPLANATION:**
As it turns out, you can "reset a select clause" multiple times from within a chain of Linq queries.  However, the "Data Transfer Object's" composition must be THE EXACT SAME throughout all queries.  As such, you simply "recast" a new returned set as you build-up the original query using said "filters".

**WHY NOT MATERIALIZE IT FIRST?:**
If I materialize it, then I am manipulating objects in-memory.  This way, I can let Entity Framework optimize the query through a Materialization Plan first.

...yay!

**WHY DO I LIKE THIS?:**
The original query is useful without worry as to the "Workflow or Object State" of any entities within the original query.  However, other scenarios demand I care about the current "State" of various entities.  Now, I can simply apply a filter to the original query anytime I want...without rewriting variations of the original query. Also, notice I didn't need to Materialize the query to accomplish this.

So...

- One query
- Multiple filters
- Filters can either refine records or append into them

...I like that.

**FINAL QUERY:** 
Here, I am simply adding "MeterObjectState" to the DeciveDataItem listing of properties.  remember, you can "re-cast" the query MULTIPLE TIMES...but only if the SELECT CLAUSE stays the same throughout the lifetime of the query.

```
public IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> Query()
{
    var query = from device in UnitOfWork.Device
                join rtuDevice in UnitOfWork.RTUDevice on device.Id equals rtuDevice.DeviceId into rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN
                from rtuDevice in rtuDeviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join commTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.CommunicationTechnicianId equals commTech.Id into commTechLEFTJOIN
                from commTech in commTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join measureTech in UnitOfWork.User on rtuDevice.MeasurementTechnicianId equals measureTech.Id into measureTechLEFTJOIN
                from measureTech in measureTechLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meter in UnitOfWork.Meter on device.Id equals meter.DeviceId into meterLEFTJOIN
                from meter in meterLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meterType in UnitOfWork.MeterType on meter.MeterTypeId equals meterType.Id into meterTypeLEFTJOIN
                from meterType in meterTypeLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join company in UnitOfWork.Company on meter.CompanyId equals company.Id into companyLEFTJOIN
                from company in companyLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join meterPosition in UnitOfWork.EFMMeterPosition on meter.EFMMeterPositionId equals meterPosition.Id into meterPositionLEFTJOIN
                from meterPosition in meterPositionLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join runStatus in UnitOfWork.RunStatus on meter.RunStatusId equals runStatus.Id into runStatusLEFTJOIN
                from runStatus in runStatusLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join pipeline in UnitOfWork.Pipeline on meter.PipelineId equals pipeline.Id into pipelineLEFTJOIN
                from pipeline in pipelineLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new DeviceDataItem()
                {
                    DeviceId = device.Id,
                    DeviceName = device.DeviceName,
                    MeterPositionId = meterPosition.Id,
                    MeterPositionCategory = meterPosition.EFMMeterPositionCategory,
                    MeterId = meter.Id,
                    MeterName = meter.MeterName,
                    MeterNumber = meter.MeterNumber,
                    MeterTypeId = meterType.Id,
                    MeterTypeName = meterType.MeterTypeName,
                    CompanyId = company.Id,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                    PipelineId = pipeline.Id,
                    PipelineName = pipeline.PipelineName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianId = commTech.Id,
                    CommunicationTechnicianFirstName = commTech.FirstName,
                    CommunicationTechnicianLastName = commTech.LastName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianId = measureTech.Id,
                    MeasurementTechnicianFirstName = measureTech.FirstName,
                    MeasurementTechnicianLastName = measureTech.LastName,
                    RunStatusId = runStatus.Id,
                    RunStatusCategory = runStatus.RunStatusCategory,
                    MeterObjectState = null
                };

    return query;
}
```

**FINAL FILTER:** 
Here, I am populating a desired property & returning a "fresh" set...

```
public IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> MeterWorkflowFilter(IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> query)
{
    Type context = typeof(Meter);

    var deviceState = (from objectState in UnitOfWork.ObjectState
                       join workflow in UnitOfWork.Workflow on objectState.WorkflowId equals workflow.Id
                       where
                            objectState.ContextFullName == context.FullName
                       group objectState by objectState.ContextId into grp
                       select grp.OrderByDescending(desc => desc.CreateDate).FirstOrDefault());

    // NOTE: Not all Devices will immediately have a Meter
    var filteredQuery = (from dataitems in query //<-- QUERY
                         join statefulDevice in deviceState on dataitems.MeterId equals statefulDevice.ContextId into statefulDeviceLEFTJOIN
                         from statefulDevice in statefulDeviceLEFTJOIN.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new DeviceDataItem()
                         {
                             DeviceId = dataitems.DeviceId,
                             DeviceName = dataitems.DeviceName,
                             MeterPositionId = dataitems.MeterPositionId,
                             MeterPositionCategory = dataitems.MeterPositionCategory,
                             MeterId = dataitems.MeterId,
                             MeterName = dataitems.MeterName,
                             MeterNumber = dataitems.MeterNumber,
                             MeterTypeId = dataitems.MeterTypeId,
                             MeterTypeName = dataitems.MeterTypeName,
                             CompanyId = dataitems.CompanyId,
                             CompanyName = dataitems.CompanyName,
                             PipelineId = dataitems.PipelineId,
                             PipelineName = dataitems.PipelineName,
                             CommunicationTechnicianId = dataitems.CommunicationTechnicianId,
                             CommunicationTechnicianFirstName = dataitems.CommunicationTechnicianFirstName,
                             CommunicationTechnicianLastName = dataitems.CommunicationTechnicianLastName,
                             MeasurementTechnicianId = dataitems.MeasurementTechnicianId,
                             MeasurementTechnicianFirstName = dataitems.MeasurementTechnicianFirstName,
                             MeasurementTechnicianLastName = dataitems.MeasurementTechnicianLastName,
                             RunStatusId = dataitems.RunStatusId,
                             RunStatusCategory = dataitems.RunStatusCategory,
                             MeterObjectState = statefulDevice.Workflow
                         });

    return filteredQuery;
}
```

Comment: [You were so preoccupied with whether or not you **could**, that you didn’t stop to think if you **should**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nazm3_OXac).

Answer (score 0):

If you get Microsoft's Interactive Extensions (Ix) - just NuGet "System.Interactive" - then you can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var foos = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo() { Bar = 1 }
    };

    foreach (var f in foos.Do(f => f.Bar = 42))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Bar);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Bar;
}
```

This outputs `42`.

Comment: Thank you!  However, this is Linq to Objects...would using this Materialize a query?  If you can show it doesn't Materialize the query I will mark YOUR ANSWER as correct :-)

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - Calling `.Do(...)` is a deferred operation. You need to execute the enumerable to make it do its thing. Is that what you mean by "Materialize"?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - The source is here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/Do.cs

Comment: Before "hydrating" the results...EF creates & optimizes the SQL through a (dynamic) Materialization Plan.  I want THAT PLAN to do the heavy lifting...SO THAT...upon enumerating the object there is NO IN-MEMORY work left to do.  That is what I mean :-)  It looks like this still does in-memory work...but Thank You for the help :-)

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - Yes, this is `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - You're not going to get anything that works on `IQueryable<T>` though - remember it has to translate to valid SQL. You really need to bring it in to memory. Do keep in mind that with EF it is often **much faster** to bring the items in to memory and do the processing there. EF doesn't always produce the most efficient queries - so in-memory work in conjunction with a simple DB query can be significantly faster.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  The query gets "Materialized or Hydrated"...then...a ForEach operation must occur on each row in-memory.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - And that approach is usually much faster.